# Using Google Drive API with PHP on website shows not verified message

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm checking [Google Drive API docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app#example) because I want to use it in the browser and not in command line, so, according to examples, my code is like this:

**index.php**

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('11*****.apps.googleusercontent.com_client_secret.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
 $drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
 $files = $drive->files->listFiles(array())->getFiles();
 echo json_encode($files);
} else {
 $redirect_uri = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/drive/oauth2callback.php';
 header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

?>
```

**oauth2callback.php**

```
<?php
  require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

  session_start();

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setAuthConfigFile('11*****.apps.googleusercontent.com_client_secret.json');
  $client->setRedirectUri('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/drive/oauth2callback.php');
  $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

  if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
   $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
   header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
  } else {
   $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
   $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
   $redirect_uri = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/drive/';
   header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
  }
?>
```

But when I execute **index.php** in the browser and after login with my google account I receive this message:

[image]

How can I avoid this message?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through verification before you launch a user-facing app. You can continue to build and test your application while waiting to complete verification. When your app is successfully verified, the unverified app screen will be removed from your client.

You can follow the steps of verification for apps [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865).